# How to plot a QQ plot with 2 samples in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to plot a QQ plot with x as one sample and y as another (not the common ones which x-axis=theoretical and y-axis=sample) using ggplot2. Does anyone know how to do this?

The common one would be, for example:

```
ggplot(df, aes(sample=sample)) + stat_qq()
```

I am able to do this with qqplot() function,

```
qqplot(sample1,sample2)
```

but it seems cannot display multiple plots with grid.arrange(). Or maybe anyone knows some other ways to plot multiple sub-qqplot at one plot?

Answer (score 8):

It's not clear if this is what you mean, but you can add 2 `stat_qq` calls on the same plot:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(69)

sample1 <- rnorm(100)
sample2 <- rnorm(100)

ggplot() + 
  stat_qq(aes(sample = sample1), colour = "green") + 
  stat_qq(aes(sample = sample2), colour = "red") +
  geom_abline(aes(slope = 1, intercept = 0), linetype = 2)
```

[image]

The other possibility is that you mean to have one sample on the x axis and one sample on the y axis to compare their relative ordering. You could do that like this:

```
ggplot(mapping = aes(x = sort(sample1), y = sort(sample2))) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline(aes(slope = 1, intercept = 0), linetype = 2)
```

[image]

---

**Edit**

From the comments, it is clear the OP is looking for an empirical qq plot of two vectors. This function should provide a rough ggplot equivalent of the function referenced in the comments:

```
gg_qq_empirical <- function(a, b, quantiles = seq(0, 1, 0.01))
{
  a_lab <- deparse(substitute(a))
  if(missing(b)) {
    b <- rnorm(length(a), mean(a), sd(a))
    b_lab <- "normal distribution"
  }
  else b_lab <- deparse(substitute(b))
  
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = quantile(a, quantiles), 
                       y = quantile(b, quantiles))) + 
    geom_point() +
    geom_abline(aes(slope = 1, intercept = 0), linetype = 2) +
    labs(x = paste(deparse(substitute(a)), "quantiles"), 
         y = paste(deparse(substitute(b)), "quantiles"),
         title = paste("Empirical qq plot of", a_lab, "against", b_lab))
}
```

So, for example we can do:

```
qq <- gg_qq_empirical(sample1, sample2)
qq + theme_light() + coord_equal()
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2020-07-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I am looking for a ggplot2 equivalent for this function:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/EnvStats/versions/2.3.1/topics/qqPlot

So I guess it’s closer to the second plot. 

Perhaps I’m confused, is this second plot different from a scatter plot? I was thinking terms like ‘geom_qq’ or ‘stat_qq’ would appear in the second code.

Comment: @Helena yes, the second version is just like a ggplot version of the linked `qqPlot`, which you can easily test by running my above code then running `qqPlot(sample1, sample2)`. You will see you get exactly the same points plotted. This is only the case if the two vectors are the same length. Remember that if you sort a numeric vector of length `n`, then in the new arrangement, the _ith_ element will be the `i/n`th empirical quantile. In other words, in our example, the 50th element of the sorted `sample1` is also its 50th centile; the same is true of sample2.

Comment: This means when you plot two sorted vectors of the same length, you are plotting empirical quantiles against emprical quantiles, so you get an empirical qqplot. This differs from a normal scatterplot because you have ordered the x and y values independently beforehand, which you don't do in a normal scatterplot. The situation is more complex but similar if the vectors are of different lengths. `qqPlot` can handle this situation too, but if your vectors are of the same length, you get your empirical qqplot with all the benefits of ggplot by just sorting each of the vectors first.

Comment: The explanation is very clear and the code works perfectly. Many thanks, Allan!

Answer (score 1):

```
d <- tibble(Group=rep(1:2, each=200), Sample=c(rnorm(200), rnorm(200, mean=2, sd=4)))
d %>% ggplot(aes(sample=Sample)) + stat_qq() + facet_wrap(~Group)
qplot(sample=Sample, data=d, color=as.factor(Group))
```

The `stat_qq()` call gives

[image]

The `qplot()` call gives

[image]